# Dual Stack Kubernetes cluster assigning single stack IPs to pods & services

Tags: kubernetes, ipv6, ipv4, kubeadm

I am creating a dual stack Kubernetes cluster with kubeadm, and installing Calico. I am using the below configuration file for kubeadm:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 0.0.0.0
  bindPort: 6443
nodeRegistration:
  criSocket: "unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
---
kind: ClusterConfiguration
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kubernetesVersion: v1.27.1
controlPlaneEndpoint: "{{ cp_endpoint }}:6443"
networking:
  serviceSubnet: "10.96.0.0/16,2a12:f840:42:1::/112"
  podSubnet: "10.244.0.0/14,2a12:f840:1:1::/56"
  dnsDomain: "cluster.local"
---
kind: KubeletConfiguration
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
cgroupDriver: systemd
```

The cluster starts up and the node is marked as ready. However, the CoreDNS and Calico Kube Controllers pods never become ready. See the output from `kubectl get pods -A -o wide below`:

```
NAMESPACE         NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE     IP                                   NODE            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
calico-system     calico-kube-controllers-789dc4c76b-tw2gp   0/1     Running   5 (2m18s ago)   7m20s   2a12:f840:1:9d:d490:4faf:378d:fd03   ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
calico-system     calico-node-dvkcg                          1/1     Running   0               7m20s   10.0.1.114                           ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
calico-system     calico-typha-7578549c55-wlk6f              1/1     Running   0               7m20s   10.0.1.114                           ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
calico-system     csi-node-driver-vwz2h                      2/2     Running   0               7m20s   2a12:f840:1:9d:d490:4faf:378d:fd00   ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
kube-system       coredns-5d78c9869d-fwc5g                   0/1     Running   0               7m27s   2a12:f840:1:9d:d490:4faf:378d:fd01   ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
kube-system       coredns-5d78c9869d-r98d6                   0/1     Running   0               7m27s   2a12:f840:1:9d:d490:4faf:378d:fd02   ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
kube-system       etcd-ip-10-0-1-114                         1/1     Running   0               7m42s   10.0.1.114                           ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
kube-system       kube-apiserver-ip-10-0-1-114               1/1     Running   0               7m42s   10.0.1.114                           ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
kube-system       kube-controller-manager-ip-10-0-1-114      1/1     Running   0               7m43s   10.0.1.114                           ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
kube-system       kube-proxy-hlq74                           1/1     Running   0               7m27s   10.0.1.114                           ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
kube-system       kube-scheduler-ip-10-0-1-114               1/1     Running   0               7m42s   10.0.1.114                           ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
tigera-operator   tigera-operator-549d4f9bdb-c2c8m           1/1     Running   0               7m27s   10.0.1.114                           ip-10-0-1-114   <none>           <none>
```

When inspecting the logs for the CoreDNS pods, I get the below error:

```
[WARNING] plugin/kubernetes: Kubernetes API connection failure: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/version": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
```

A similar error is seen in the Calico Kube Controllers pod's logs:

```
2023-06-15 10:17:18.315 [ERROR][1] client.go 290: Error getting cluster information config ClusterInformation="default" error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
2023-06-15 10:17:18.315 [INFO][1] main.go 138: Failed to initialize datastore error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
```

These pods receive IPv6 addresses and when inspecting the main kube-system services (e.g. API controller, DNS, etc.), they all have IPv4 addresses only. My assumption is that both pods and services for core services should be fully dual stack. However, I don't know which configuration options enable this in addition to those I have already added.

The below description of the kubernetes service seems to back this up: `kubectl describe service kubernetes`

```
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.96.0.1
IPs:               10.96.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        6443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.0.2.167:6443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I attempted to add the below to the ClusterConfiguration, which didn't make any impact.

```
controllerManager:
  extraArgs:
    cluster-cidr: "10.244.0.0/14,2a12:f840:1:1::/56"
    service-cluster-ip-range: "10.96.0.0/16,2a12:f840:42:1::/112"
```

I also attempted to register the node IP addresses directly in the configuration using the below:

```
kubeletExtraArgs:
    node-ip: 10.0.2.167,2a05:d01c:345:dc03:aeb6:5cde:e434:1c34
```

This did then list both IP addresses in the node description, but made no impact on the connectivity:

```
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.0.2.167
  InternalIP:  2a05:d01c:345:dc03:aeb6:5cde:e434:1c34
```